# Writing to window after opening it with window.open() doesn't work

Tags: javascript, dom

Basically, I need to open a window. I need to fill this window with HTML. Now here is my issue. When I do something akin to `window.open().document.write("HTML")`, it doesn't show up. It simply shows `about:blank` and a blank white screen as if I never wrote to it. I've already tried using the window's `document.body.innerHTML` to write to it, but I recieve the same results. I've been able to recreate this in my script and in Chrome DevTools, so it's not an issue with my script.

Comment: `window.open()` returns a `Window`, `document`-property of which is read-only. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window

Comment: Seems to work on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g20bn7rh/). What's your context? How exactly are you running your script?

Comment: I'm running this in the Chrome DevTools on the New Tab page. But for some reason, it does work in JsFiddle. Weird.

Comment: Turns out that this only occurs on the Chrome New Tab page. Closing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that for some reason, when running this on the Chrome New Tab page(it's a chrome extension that needs to be able to run outside of a chrome extension), it doesn't work. I don't know why this happens, but it does.